# QXmpp Client confirmation of successful authorization

Tags: qt, xmpp

I'm wondering whether or not QXmpp client sends the query that confirms succeeded authorization on it's side, having received response from server about authorization response (?).

As far as I am aware, QXmpp (that is XMPP as well) protocol based on TCP, so I suppose it ought to (each sides) confirm
that received packet successfully.

Comment: That kind of confirmation is a few layers above TCP. You should probably include the exact part of XMPP you're referring to. Just having a look with e.g. wireshark will give you the quicker and more reliable answer though.

Comment: I'm using QXmpp lib on qt. But how wireshark will lighten me through

Comment: You can just set a `QXmppLogger` in your `QXmppClient`. You can use the logger then to print out all sent and received XMPP packets.

What gave you the idea, that the authorization is not correct?